# Convert var_export from server URL string to integer

Tags: php, string, url, int, var

I have the following URL and i want to get the last number (query) to integer.

*I want the fragment but there no way to do it without javascript, so the query is ok.*

localhost/path/profile.php?**1852**

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$url = var_export(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY));
$Serial = intval($url);
```

The $Serial = intval($url); is zero all the times.

I want to get the last number as i said to check if is the same as a database column value. The database column can be int or varchar.

Also another method to do it, are welcomed.

Comment: Have you tried to explode by `?` i.e. `explode('?',$url)` Then you will get an array with the string split into an array, split by the `?` character

Comment: Just remove the `var_export()`.  It's not needed and screwing up the output.

Comment: @guyver4mk An example of the following URL; I had tried with a lot of things but nothing working.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Well, i get 0 all the times with intval($url).

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f1c52136b3168bac9a0cab6299aa0e11478aca55

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the name of the last GET parameter as an integer:

(Assuming you want to operate on the current URL, since you've used `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`).

```
end($_GET);
$serial = (int) key($_GET);
var_dump($serial);
```

Comment: `end($_GET);

$serial = (int) key($_GET);

$id = var_export($serial);`

Its give me what i want but at the where id='$id'" i am getting "("That ID is wrong.");"...

Comment: @ulb not sure what are you trying to accomplish with `var_export()` - just use `$serial` - it already contains the ID as an integer.

Comment: Yes, it's working! I confused with your var_dump, that't what hours of coding do to a newbie :P Thank you!

Comment: @ulb glad it worked :) yes.. the `var_dump()` is just an example to quickly show what the given variable contains.